# How to get a list of all the members in the Visitors-Sharepoint group using PnPPowershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Does anyone know the PnPPowershell-code for gettings all the members of a certain SharePoint-group (in my case the Visitor-group).

Greetings,

P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Get-PnPGroupMembers` command.

Use it as mentioned below where `Identity` would be the title of the group:

```
Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity "Visitors Group Name"
```

Reference - [Get-PnPGroupMembers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpgroupmembers?view=sharepoint-ps)

You can also use `Get-PnPGroup` command as well:

```
$group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "Visitors Group Name" -Includes Users
$group.Users
```

Reference - [Get-PnPGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpgroup?view=sharepoint-ps)